# Add script into HTML using vite and vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite, rollupjs

I have one js file which needs to be put in the public directory and needs to add it in the final production build as a `text/javascript`.

I have checked the options in vite config but couldn't find anything useful. The files I add contain a global JSON object and can be accessed directly.

To achieve this, I tried this solution.

**vite.config.ts**

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "url";
import path from 'path';
// import test from "./src/assets/test.js"
import test from "./public/test.js"

import { defineConfig , loadEnv} from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import { loadingScript } from 'vite-plugin-loading-script'

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  // Load env file based on `mode` in the current working directory.
  // Set the third parameter to '' to load all env regardless of the `VITE_` prefix.
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '')
  return {
    // vite config
    define: {
      __APP_ENV__: JSON.stringify(env.VITE_REDIRECT_URL),
      __TEST__: test,
    },
    plugins: [vue()],
    server: {
      hmr: {
        overlay: false,
      },
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
      },
    },
    build: {
      // rollupOptions: {
      //   external: ['__APP_ENV__'],
      //   output: {
      //     globals: {
      //       __APP_ENV__: JSON.stringify(env.VITE_REDIRECT_URL),
      //     }
      //   }
      // }
    }
  }
});
```

**test.js**

```
export default {
    REDIRECT_URL: "https://example.com/",
    API_URL: "https://example.com/",
};
```

with the above changes, I got the `console.log('__TEST__', __TEST__)` as expected JSON object but it doesn't work with the production build.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try including the js file to the html in the public directory

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).